# Is there a way to refactor this without using 3 collectors to combine strings?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor the following:

```
  def method_name
    array  = ["abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqr"]
    collector1 = ""
    collector2 = ""
    collector3 = ""
    array.each do |string|
      collector1 += string[0..1]
      collector2 += string[2..3]
      collector3 += string[4..5]
    end
    x = collector1 + "\n" + collector2 + "\n" + collector3
    # "abghmn\ncdijop\nefklqr"
  end
```

Are there any more efficient ways to write this? Or perhaps a different enumerable that will achieve the same result?

`"abghmn\ncdijop\nefklqr"` is the desired output!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def method_name
  array = ["abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqr"]
  array.map { |s| s.chars.each_slice(2).to_a }.transpose.map(&:join).join("\n")
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Appreciate you! Knew each_slice was going to have something to do with it but wasn't using it right.

Comment: `s.chars.each_slice(2).to_a` : the same result can be obtained by `s.scan(/../)`

Comment: not exactly. you should do `s.scan(/../).map(&:chars)` but good catch

Comment: @Ursus Yeah it's not very important but you don't need the chars; the 2-char strings are fine. I should have written "end-result" I guess.

Comment: You can't tranpose if you don't apply chars to them

Comment: @Ursus Why not? `array  = ["abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqr"];
puts array.map{|s| s.scan(/../)}.transpose.map(&:join).join("\n")`

Answer (score 2):

You could write the following.

```
array  = ["abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqr"]
ranges = [0..1, 2..3, 4..5]
```

```
ranges.map { |r| array.map { |s| s[r] }.join }.join('\n')
  #=> "abghmn\\ncdijop\\nefklqr"
```

or

```
ranges.map { |r| array.reduce('') { |t,s| t + s[r] } }.join('\n')
  #=> "abghmn\\ncdijop\\nefklqr"
```